# Where are JavaScript vars stored?

Tags: javascript, lambda, ecmascript-6, lisp

I was playing with common lisp a bit and realized that unlike Lisp, where all local variables are either arguments(via lambda) lambda, or via parameters(via let).

In other words, they always follow the IIFE idiom:

```
((x, y, z) => {
   /* I has variables */
})(1, 2, 3);
```

eg

```
((lambda (x y z)
    ; I has variables
) 1 2 3)
```

or

```
(let ((x 1)(y 2)(z 3))
    ; I has variables
)
```

In JavaScript, vars "feel" like setq, but setq mutate global scope if the local variable is not declared to shadow it, in JavaScript, vars don't mutate global scope no matter what.

Let's say I want to do this in Lisp:

```
(function() {
    var x = 1;
    var y = 2;
    var z = 3;

    /* woo, I has 3 vars */
})();
/*note that the vars no longer exist */
```

If I try to do this using this:

```
; progn is like lambda but never has arguments and automatically iifes itself.
; eg (progn (setq x 1)) is ((lambda () (setq x 1))
(progn
    (setq x 1)
    (setq y 2)
    (setq z 3)
    ; Woo I has 3 vars
)
; oops, I polluted global scope :(
```

To get this JavaScript-like feel, I end up doing something like

```
; wait, we're writing smalltalk now? 
; [ 
;     | x y z | 
;     x := 1.
;     y := 2.
;     z := 3.
;     "I has three vars..."
; ] value.
(let
    ((x)(y)(z))

    (setq x 1)
    (setq x 2)
    (setq x 3)
)
```

Strangely, Lisp does not seem to have a parallel to a JavaScript var/let/const; in the sense of the example above(Does it? I'm not very familiar with Lisp...).

My question is; where are vars actually stored? They are not passed as arguments and they are not explicitly declared in the parameters... But they must be stored somewhere, and that somewhere is not the global scope...

Comment: Are you asking about "functional scope"? I'm not actually clear what the question is here but, in brief - any arguments _declared_ in a function stay in the function. You can also have global variables, too and a function will also have access to them.

Comment: The question may be valid, however, JS vs Lisp comparison is quite odd. There's a bunch of languages that introduce local variables with block and function scopes, JS isn't exotic at all in this respect, it is just one of many. If 'where' addresses the way JS engines manage memory, the question should be more specific.

Comment: The idea carries along many languages. I am actually more interested about Perl lexical scope(`my $x`, whereas before my was a thing, everything was a setq since `$x` always exposes to global the same way setq does) and Lisp's lack of a similar concept of a "my" scope. That is `(sub {my $foo = 3;})->();` does not pollute global scope, whereas `(sub {$foo = 3;})->();` does and won't run if you have strict subs(strict bans setq?) But the behavior of "my $" is vary similar to var and JavaScript is much more popular than Perl at the moment. Smalltalk does not have this though, but Ruby does.

Comment: It's actually amazing how everyone prefers "var/my/our" like behavior, and is terrified by lambda/let/iife when I talk to people around my campus. Especially since closures seem more natural in terms of logic, whereas var/my/our uses magic to take care of our variables without corrupting global scope. "var/my/our" seems more complicated in terms of implementation details than "iife"s, but we find them much more natural; even to an extent of schools using "let x = 2. y = x + 3." in math instead of "(let ((x 2)) (let ((y (+ 3 x))) ...))" which is more "honest" in terms of scoping.

Comment: The "harder" thing, seems to be "easier" for us to understand, even though explicit scope should be easier since it makes the dependencies explicit; By having y = x + 3 be nested inside definition of x, you avoid a lot of ambiguity.Very strange.

Answer (score 10):

JavaScript variables are "bindings" on an object called a [*LexicalEnvironment*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-lexical-environments) object. When execution enters a scope that can have its own bindings (such as when entering a function), a new *LexicalEnvironment* is created and populated with the arguments, locals, and locally-declared functions.

This is a specification construct; how JavaScript engines actually implement it is up to the engine provided it faithfully replicates the semantics of the specification. There is nothing in the specification that lets us directly access the object. (In particular: If nothing *closes over* the variables, they can happily be implemented on a stack and cleaned up by just resetting the stack pointer on exit.)

Note that this is how *closures* work in JavaScript, so reading up on closures will give you more insight into where variables are stored. In brief: When you create a function, the function has a (somewhat indirect) reference to the active *LexicalEnvironment* object as of when it was created. Since the object contains the bindings for the variables, the function can access them via the object.

A specific example will probably help; see comments:

```js
// A function that returns a function that closes over its
// local variable
function f() {
  // When this function is called, a *LexicalEnvironment* object
  // is created and populated with an `a` variable
  // (and a few other things)
  var a = Math.random();
  
  // If we create a function, it gets a reference to the object,
  // and so it can access that variable
  return function() {
    return a;
  };
}

// Create a lexical environment containing a variable, get back
// a function with access to it
var f1 = f();

// Do it again
var f2 = f();

// Now we have *two* separate lexical environment objects (well,
// more, but two related to `f`). They both continue to exist
// as long as there's something referring to them (like all other
// objects). Our `f1` and `f2` each refer to one of them, so they
// still exist and `f1` and `f2` can use the `a` on each of them:
console.log(f1());
console.log(f2());

// Now we release the functions, which release the lexical
// environment object they had references to
f1 = f2 = undefined;
```

Comment: Would LocalEnvironment be kind of like an implicit argument to each javascript scope? eg `((lambda ((localEnvironment)) "dummy text") environmentInfo)` where each scope gets its environment injected implicitly into the body, and all vars implicitly bind to this environment, kind of like using the environment as a hash table.

Comment: @Dmitry: (*LexicalEnvironment*, not LocalEnvironment.) The spec goes into the gory details, but when you enter a scope, the engine does create a new environment object and adds it to the current chain of them; the code running within the scope uses the "active" one at the top of the chain.

Comment: is it possible to access lexical environment object directly from a javascript scope? I cant find it

Comment: @Dmitry: No, as I said in the answer, the spec doesn't provide any means of directly accessing that object.

Comment: so it just implicitly handled via "="s, "function", "class", "var/let/const", and such? otherwise its a linked hash table of environments?

Comment: @Dmitry: Right, it's handled by the engine's own identifier resolution, which uses a chain of lexical environment objects (starting with the innermost, then the next one out, etc.).

Comment: so would it be safe to say that Lisp has no "Lexical Scoping"? Or is there another word for what i'm trying to say? Lexical Environment Bindings? implicit  Lexical Environment Bindings?

Comment: @Dmitry: I'm afraid I can't comment on Lisp at all; I know next to nothing about it. Perhaps Rainer can help with the Lisp part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127955/discussion-between-dmitry-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: Sorry I've been playing with Lisp, Smalltalk, Perl, and JavaScript so much lately that I see them as a single language with varying degree of automation/runtime power/sugar that can easily be added since the languages are capable of passing themselves through regular expressions before doing eval to restrict behavior or automate common behavior with new constructs. I think it's possible to write Perl in Lisp, Smalltalk in Perl, and JavaScript in Smalltalk or Perl, by simply doing transformations and adding runtime constructs, and adding constraints/hiding. Maybe even JavaScript in Lisp.

Answer (score 5):

In Common Lisp assigning a variable with something like `setq` does not declare the variable as such. There is no mechanism for such block scope, where mentioning a variable will create it in the inner most block scope.

You mentioned `let` and `lambda` already.

Note that `lambda` has `&aux` variables:

```
(lambda (&aux (x 1) (y 2) (z 3))

  ; x and y and z are variables here...

  )
```

These *auxiliary* variables need to be declared in the lambda parameter list, but are not a part of the arguments with which one calls a function.

Example:

```
CL-USER 61 > ((lambda (x &aux (y (* x x)) (z 12))
                (+ y x z))
              5)
42
```

Your example

```
CL-USER 63 > (let (x y z)

               (setq x 1)
               (setq y 2)
               (setq z 3)

               (+ x y z))
6
```

was a popular option, especially because years ago it was usually written as:

```
CL-USER 72 > (prog (x y z)

               (setq x 1)
               (setq y 2)
               (setq z 3)

               (return (+ x y z)))
6
```

`prog` provides a *block*, local variables and a *tagbody*. In a tagbody we can have local *tag* and jumps via a *go to* construct.

**Summary**: This means you can have block local or function local variables, but you have to declare them first in Common Lisp. In some other languages you can do that anywhere in the body of some scope.

When you enter a block, this way, the list of lexical variables is known and fixed. The language implementation does not need to scan the body for new variables and it does not need to provide some way to extend the current lexical environment with new variables.

Comment: Comments/discussion not related to this question/answer and relevant to this [meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337772/should-this-question-be-separated) have been movd [to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127957/discussion-on-answer-by-rainer-joswig-where-are-javascript-vars-stored).

Comment: `In Common Lisp assigning a variable with something like setq does not declare the variable as such. There is no mechanism for such block scope, where mentioning a variable will create it in the inner most block scope.`. What is this mechanism called? `Lexical Scope` includes both implicit and explicit declaration, but what about specifically "var" or perl's "my/our" behavior?($ acts very similar to setq without any words before it)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer but it is too long for a comment: sorry.

There are three possibilities for creating variable bindings that seem to be common:

1. variables are explicitly bound at the start of a scope;
2. there is a construct which creates a binding which can occur anywhere in a scope, but it's not just assignment;
3. variables get implicitly bound in a surrounding scope on their first assignment.

An example of (3) is Python.  Languages which do this end up needing explicit scope-resolution operators (`global` and now `nonlocal` in Python) to deal with the stupid, lazy, pun they have done and are not worth discussing further: you need binding constructs which are distinct from assignment or you end up living in pain for ever.

Common Lisp is an example of (1), and C used to be: they are both (C was) examples of languages where all the bindings needed to be created at the start of a scope construct.

Within (1) there are languages which have some kind of block construct (`{` ... `}` in C) which can be used for grouping *and* for scope, and ones which have a grouping construct and one or more separate scoping constructs: CL is in the latter family.

So in (old) C you would say

```
{
    int i = 3;
    ...
}
```

While in CL you say

```
(let ((i 3)) ...)
```

-- the scope construct here is `let` (and there are others of course).

Of course, CL, being a Lisp, can perfectly happily invent a construct which looks like C's blocks:

```
(defmacro scope (&body vars/body)
  (loop for (var? . body?) on vars/body
        while (and (listp var?)
                   (<= 2 (length var?) 3)
                   (eql (first var?) 'var)
                   (symbolp (second var?)))
        collect (case (length var?)
                  (2 (second var?))
                  (3 (rest var?))) into bindings
        finally (return `(let* ,bindings ,var? ,@body?))))
```

And now

```
(scope
  (var a)
  (var b 2)
  ...)
```

is a construct in the language.

So really these two variants on (1) are more similar than they are different: it's just a matter of how you cut up the underlying constructs you want in the language: C conflated scope blocks and grouping, CL doesn't.

(2) is different however.  Here you are allowed to intermingle binding constructs and other things within a scope construct.  C is now like this, and so is JavaScript.  CL is *not* like this natively (obviously, being a Lisp, it could *become* like this with some macrology, although that macrology would be a lot hairier than what I wrote above).

In such a language you really need a separate binding-creation construct, because it can't be part of the scoping construct.  Languages like C already treat the binding-creation construct as separate, so for them it's just a matter of relaxing the rule which says bindings must all be created at the start of a scope construct.

Languages like this have a significant question to answer though: what *is* the scope of a binding?  Does something like

```
{
    ...
    int x = 3;
    ...
}
```

Really mean

```
{
    ...
    {
        int x = 3;
        ...
    }
}
```

or does it mean

```
{
    int x;
    ...
    x = 3;
    ...
}
```

The latter case is easier, but means that there's an awkward region where references to `x` are legal but its value may not be well-defined.  C takes the former interpretation I think.

This is mostly fine for languages like C where the grouping construct is the same as the scoping construct.  But it's not fine for languages like JavaScript where the grouping construct is not the scoping construct and, worse, where there is no scoping construct other than functions (or used not to be).  And in fact languages like that can't really fix the problem, since there's no useful scoping construct.  Well, of course, they fix it by growing a scoping construct.

Note that although CL is a (1) language there are Lisp-family languages which are (2) languages: in particular [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) is.  In Racket (but not, I think, in Scheme) you can say

```
(define (foo)
  (define bar 1)
  ;; is baz bound here?
  (display bar)
  (define baz 3)
  (list bar baz))
```

And the answer is that yes, `baz` is bound there, but it's bound to an undefined object and you'll get an error (at run time, not compile time) if you try to use it.  So this is a run-time error:

(define (foo)
      (define bar 1)
      (display baz)
      (define baz 3)
      (list bar baz))

while this

```
(define (foo)
  (define bar 1)
  (display baz)
  (let ()
    (define baz 3)
    (list bar baz)))
```

is a compile time error.  (I am actually slightly confused about which constructs in Racket create scopes.)

Comment: isn't it natural to allow different kinds of assignments since it disambiguates the job of the assignment?(if one assignment is responsible for all kinds of assignment, it has to be cluttered with if statements because it doesn't know if it must preform a cheap global symbol allocation or traverse the environment chain and only if there is no symbol named foo, add the symbol to the symbol table).

Comment: Also, which category of the three does creating a scope dictionary for the scope closure where each scope created in it creates a scope dictionary where parent scope dictionary is null, whereas if there is an environment dictionary, the new dictionary's parent key gets set to the dictionary of the scope it is contained in, which already has the pointers to its parent if any.

Comment: @Dmitry: an assignment in a lexically-scoped language never has to do any of that stuff: where a variable is bound is always known at compile time (that's pretty much the definition of being lexically-scoped).  All this stuff about dictionaries and so on is some hack which languages defined by their (rudimentary) implementations have chosen to expose, for no good reason at all.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood the answers  correctly, the behavior looks something like this:

```
var env_get = function(env, varname) {
    var tenv = env;

    while (true) {    
        if (tenv.hasOwnProperty(varname)) {
            return tenv[varname];
        } else {
            if (tenv.superenv == null) {
                throw "no such variable" + tenv;
            } else {
                tenv = tenv.superenv;
            }
        }
    }
};

(function(superenv) {
    var env = {
        'superenv': superenv,
        'one': 1
    };

    console.log(env_get(env, "one"));

    (function(superenv) {
        var env = {
            'superenv': superenv,
            'two': 2
        };
        console.log(env_get(env, "one"));
        console.log(env_get(env, "two"));

        (function(superenv) {
            var env = {
                'superenv': superenv,
                'three': 3
            }                        
            console.log(env_get(env, "one"));
            console.log(env_get(env, "two"));                
            console.log(env_get(env, "three"));
        })(env);
    })(env);
})(null);
```

or in Lisp:

```
(defun env_get (env varname) (let
    ((tenv))
    (setq tenv env)

    (loop (let
        ((val))

        (setq val (gethash varname tenv))
        (if val
            (return val)
            (let
                ((superenv))
                (setq superenv (gethash 'superenv tenv))

                (if superenv
                    (setq tenv superenv)
                    (return 'undefined)
                )
            )
        )
    ))
))

((lambda (superenv) (let 
    ((env))

    (setq env (make-hash-table))
    (setf (gethash 'superenv env) nil)
    (setf (gethash 'one env) 1)

    (print (env_get env 'one))
    (print (env_get env 'two))
    (print (env_get env 'three))     

    ((lambda (superenv) (let        
        ((env))

        (setq env (make-hash-table))
        (setf (gethash 'superenv env) superenv)
        (setf (gethash 'two env) 2)

        (print (env_get env 'one))
        (print (env_get env 'two))
        (print (env_get env 'three))  

        ((lambda (superenv) (let        
            ((env))

            (setq env (make-hash-table))
            (setf (gethash 'superenv env) superenv)
            (setf (gethash 'two env) 2)
            (setf (gethash 'three env) 3)

            (print (env_get env 'one))
            (print (env_get env 'two))
            (print (env_get env 'three))                    
        )) env)                    
    )) env)    
)) nil)
```